# How do I transform a complicated character string (Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009) into a date/time in r?

Tags: r, date, time, character, lubridate

I want to transform a date in a character string Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009 into a POSIXct date.

I tried

```
dt <- strptime(df$date, "%a %b %d %H%M%S %Y")
```

and

```
datee <- parse_date_time(twit$date, "%a %b %d! %H!%M!%S! %Y!")
```

tand got either got NA or an error message.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can convert a date-time string with an embedded time zone specifier

```
x2 <- "Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 2009"
strptime(x2,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
## [1] "2009-04-06 22:19:45 EDT"
```

You could use regular expressions to extract the time zone and use it as the `tz` argument:

```
strptime(x2,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y",tz="PDT")
## [1] "2009-04-06 22:19:45 PDT"
```

As @akrun suggests,

```
x3 <- 'Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT 2009'
as.POSIXct(x3, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S PDT %Y", tz='PDT') 
## [1] "2009-04-06 22:19:45 PDT"
```

Or equivalently

```
strptime(x3, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S PDT %Y", tz='PDT')
```

If you don't know in advance that the data are going to be PDT, this will take some more work ...